# What four directions which are not described by 四处 are described by 八方?

Tags: word-choice, phrase

I have a hunch about the difference between 八方 and 四处.

四处 includes north, south, west and east. 八方 includes these four + up, down, forward, backward.

Three questions:

1. Is my assumption correct?
2. Do native speakers really differenciate between these two phrases or they use them interchangibly?
3. Is there a reason why 八 is connected with 方 and not with 处? Is there a difference in the sense of "direction" given by 方 and 处?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**四方** / **四处**

*[现代汉语大词典](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%8E%B0%E4%BB%A3%E6%B1%89%E8%AF%AD%E5%A4%A7%E8%AF%8D%E5%85%B8/1652770)*

> 东南西北四个方向

- 四处 (or 四方) = north, south, east and west

---

**八方**

*[古汉语大词典](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%8F%A4%E6%B1%89%E8%AF%AD%E5%A4%A7%E8%AF%8D%E5%85%B8)*

> 四方(东、南、西、北)四隅(东南、东北、西南、西北)的总称。

- 八方 = (north, south, east and west) + southeast,  northeast, southwest and northwest

---

四方 and 四处 can be used interchangeably. There is also a third one: 四面.

Another word you might want to know:

- 十面 = ((north, south, east and west) + southeast,  northeast, southwest and northwest) + up and down.

八处 doesn't seem to be a thing, but 八面 does exist.

Comment: 十 in 十面 is a metaphorical number. It implies 'all'  or 'total' as in 十面埋伏 (ambush in all directions); 十全十美 (perfect in all aspects)

Answer (score 1):

Many Chinese numbers are used as a metaphorical number

- 四 in 四处 (everywhere) doesn't mean 'four', it means 'every'
- 四 in 四面 (all sides) doesn't mean 'four', it means 'all'
- When 面 is used as a classifier, 四 would be a regular number 'four' e.g. 房屋的四面墙 (the four walls of the house)
- 八 in 八方 (all directions) doesn't mean 'eight', it means 'all'
- 四面八方 is more often written as 四方八面, both mean 'everywhere; all directions'
- 十 in 十面 (all sides) doesn't mean 'ten', it means 'all' or total as in 十面埋伏 (ambush in all directions); 十全十美 (perfect in all aspects)

Answer (score 0):

四面、八方、十方、十面 or 四面八方 usually means everywhere or every directions.

e.g.

從四面八方過來的人潮讓這裡熱鬧非凡。(It means people come from everywhere instead of from east, west, north, south..etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I take 四处 as ***everywhere***, 八方 ***north, south, west and east，northeast, Northwest, southeast, southwest***.

Basically, they are not interchangeable.  E. g.  你四处找找。 not 你八方找找。

八方 is usually used in the phrase 四面八方(from all the directions;everywhere).  E. g. 四面八方到处都是人。